# WooCommerce Rest API - adding product author to products list

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using WooCommerce with WC Vendors plugin. I am trying to return vendor name and id when returning the product list through the API call (`/wp-json/wc/v3/products`)

I have been advised to use the following code in functions.php:

```
function filter_woocommerce_api_product_response( $product_data, $product, $fields, $this_server ) { 
    $product_data['vendor_id'] = get_post_field( 'post_author', $product->id);
    $product_data['vendor_name'] = get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $product_data['vendor_id']);
    return $product_data; 
};      
add_filter( 'woocommerce_api_product_response', 'filter_woocommerce_api_product_response', 10, 4 );
```

The data I get does not contain either the vendor_id or vendor_name.

Comment: Did you debug your code? Is it entering to the function? Is it finding the author information and correctly assigning it to `$product_data`? If all of that is happening, then there may be another filter interfering with yours. You can try to set a higher priority (3rd parameters in your `add_filter` call) and see what happens. Try with priority 1.
`add_filter( 'woocommerce_api_product_response', 'filter_woocommerce_api_product_response', 1, 4 ); `

Comment: Hi, thanks for this - I have tried changing the priority as you have suggested and I do not get vendor_id or vendor_name returned. I am relatively new to this - what is the best way to debug the code?

Comment: Either logging to the log (`error_log`) or dumping your variables and see if the code gets there (`var_dump`, `print_r`, `echo`)

Answer (score 1):

Adding this code to your theme’s functions.php file:

```
if ( post_type_exists( 'product' ) ) {
add_post_type_support( 'product', 'author' );
}
```

Hope it helps you out!